# [rospack] Error: package 'beginner_tutorials' not found

Tags: ros-kinetic, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the tutorials for ROS kinetic and in the writing a publisher and subscriber in C++ after copying the cpp files in the src folder of beginner_tutorials folder i pass:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws 
catkin_make
```

When I build the workspace using catkin_make after copying the talker.cpp and listener.cpp in the ~catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src i get the following output:

```
    ros@ros-HP-280-G2-SFF:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
    Base path: /home/ros/catkin_ws
    Source space: /home/ros/catkin_ws/src
    Build space: /home/ros/catkin_ws/build
    Devel space: /home/ros/catkin_ws/devel
    Install space: /home/ros/catkin_ws/install
    ####
    #### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/ros/catkin_ws/build"
    ####

####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/ros/catkin_ws/build"
####
```

then when i open new terminal and pass

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
rosrun beginner_tutorials talker
```

the errors are as follows:

```
 [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named talker below /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials
```

When I see this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZQ-GfJ4ZIg&list=PLk51HrKSBQ8-jTgD0qgRp1vmQeVSJ5SQC&index=8) they are also following the same steps and while they give catkin_make command the output has few more lines like

```
[50%] Built target talker
[100%] Built target listener
```

which I am not getting.

I tried the solutions mentioned to similar problems, tried to chmod +x talker.cpp in the src folder of the package. Still getting the same error

PLEASE HELP ME TO UNDERSTAND WHAT I AM DOING WRONG﻿. MANY THANKS IN ADVANCE

PS: I am an engineer from mechanical branch with little experience in coding, usually I copy+paste of the errors in google helps me solve them from people who have previously faced and solved.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319337/%5Brospack%5D-error:-package-%27beginner_tutorials%27-not-found/) by [designthala](https://answers.ros.org/users/40595/designthala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-03-24**:
Can you please edit the question and add your CMakeLists.txt file here?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-25**:
It's likely that @designthala hasn't added the `talker` and `listener` targets to their `CMakeLists.txt`, causing Catkin to not actually build anything. That would explain both the missing lines in the build output and the fact that the nodes cannot be found by `rosrun`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Many thanks @gvdhoorn you are right!

I read something about adding targets to the CMakeLists.txt in some solutions but I didnt know what it means so I ignored those instructions.

Now after going through the ROS Kinetic Tutorials page slowly I found out that by adding the below mentioned lines at the end of the CMakeLists.txt present in

> /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials

the catkin_make command builds both the cpp files in the src folder:

```
add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp) 
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp) 

add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp) 
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES}) 
add_dependencies(listener beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)
```

Thank you @janindu and @gvdhoorn for extending helping hands!

---

Originally posted by [designthala](https://answers.ros.org/users/40595/designthala/) with karma: 16 on 2019-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0